# UICollection View and UITable View inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistackview

I am using an UIStackView to add up UILabels along with UITableView and UICollectionView. When the data is loaded into the views only UILabels are shown.

I have not added any constraints in the views so could you please help me know what behavior of UIStackView is not allowing me to show UITableView and UICollectionView.

But if I add height constraints to the view then it works but the view gets messy. On Scrolling the main View in which the UIStackView is present after data load operation is finished, the view is seen correctly.

I am adding the view I wanted when the Main View first loads in the attachment.
[image: Before Scrolling (No Tableview and collectionview)]

[image: After scrolling the view is managed with spacing but there is no tableview and collectionview]

Comment: I am not getting you Q completely. So, can you show us both the screen shots i.e. before & after setting height constraints? And one more thing, I don`t thing its because of stack view, I thing you missing something with your layout constraints.

Comment: Please provide more information on what the expected behavior is. You have mentioned UITableView within a UITableViewCell, are these dynamic cells whose height is calculated programmatically?

Comment: I havent set height constraints to the uicollectionview and uitableview

Comment: @Preson yes it is dynamic cell. Here I have created the custom cell for maintableview and the figure shows the 0 index cell.

Comment: @SagarSukode i have updated the question